# Application crashing on IOS 5 working on previous versions

Tags: iphone, xcode4, ios5

My application was launched on the App Store on Oct. 5. It is working well on all iOS versions except iOS 5. On a particular class it is crashing on this statement:

```
[[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:lastIndex] 
  setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
```

I am getting the error "Executing Bad Access."

Could this be because of ARC, introduced by Apple in iOS 5?

Comment: can you give us the read out xcode gives you when it crashes? give us a few lines above and below the error line

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with ARC since that version of your app was never compiled with ARC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That indexPath should be retained.

Add `[lastIndex retain];`  before your statement.

Comment: Thanks dude,It worked thanks a lot butnow its is crashing at 'MyViewController *m=[[[MyViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:Nil]autorelease];
                [self.navigationController pushViewController:m animated:YES];' Its is giving SIGBRT and still it is working good on all previous versions